# Как распарсить URL с русским текстом

Tags: node.js, парсер

Проблема заключается в том что есть URL-ссылка которая содержит русский текст вываливается с ошибкой *SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input*. Если использовать английские слова в ссылке то всё хорошо отрабатывает, как с этим бороться помогите пожалуйста.

```
let urlwow = `https://eu.api.battle.net/wow/character/Сервер/Петя?fields=items&locale=ru_RU&apikey=${apikey}`;
request(urlwow, (error, response, bodywow) => 
{      
  let datawow = JSON.parse(bodywow);  
  console.log(datawow);      
});
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что проблема в этом коде, а не на сервере? Если просто открыть эту ссылку в новой вкладке браузера, что будет? `console.log(bodywow)` что показывает? (перед JSON.parse естественно)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) для русских фрагментов

```
let urlwow = `https://eu.api.battle.net/wow/character/${encodeURIComponent('Сервер')}/${encodeURIComponent('Петя')}?fields=items&locale=ru_RU&apikey=${apikey}`;
request(urlwow, (error, response, bodywow) => 
{      
    let datawow = JSON.parse(bodywow);  
    console.log(datawow);      
});
```

Comment: У меня отработало, сервер вернул корректный JSON.